# Send from free Gmail account via PHP

Tags: email, php, gmail, dns, dkim

I want to send email via PHP script using my free Gmail as the `From` sender. How can this be done such that the SPF records will be valid (as if the mail was actually sent from Gmail)?

Answer (score 5):

There are many other libraries as well. Some of them are :

- http://phpmailer.worxware.com/
- http://pear.php.net/package/Mail (This is Pear package)
- https://github.com/denvertimothy/ThriveSMTP
- http://swiftmailer.org/

You can send the mail from PHP using SMTP using any of these libraries

An example of sending mail using your Gmail account with PHPMailer library  will be :

```
//include the file
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$phpmailer          = new PHPMailer();


$phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$phpmailer->Host       = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$phpmailer->Port       = 465;          // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server; 465 for ssl and 587 for tls
$phpmailer->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // Gmail account username
$phpmailer->Password   = "yourpassword";        // Gmail account password

$phpmailer->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last'); //set from name

$phpmailer->Subject    = "Subject";
$phpmailer->MsgHTML($body);

$phpmailer->AddAddress($to, "To Name");

if(!$phpmailer->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $phpmailer->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

As one of the solutions, you can use Zend Framework `Zend_Mail` class

```
    $email_conf = array(
        'auth' => 'login',
        'username' => 'your_login',
        'password' => 'your_password',
        'ssl' => 'tls',
        'port' => '587'
    );
    $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $email_conf);
    Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);

    $mailer = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
    $mail->addTo($recipientEmail); 
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    $mailer->setBodyHtml($html);
    $mail->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to send the message through Google's SMTP servers. If you need pure PHP, find a SMTP library (I only know of [Net_SMTP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP) from PEAR) and configure it for `smtp.gmail.com` with the usual settings that Gmail gives you.